# DNN MVC Module not posting file back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, post, dotnetnuke

I am building a small DNN MVC module whereby I need a user to upload file which will be processed server side.

When the form is posted back, the view model is posted back fine, but the file never is.  Request.Files is always 0.

I even simplified it so all I had on the module was a simple file input and submit button but that failed as well.

I would hate to have to revert back to .ascx controls to get this to work.

I am testing this as an unregistered user, therefore there is no authentication checking in the controller.

See code below:

**View**

```
@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.DnnWebViewPage<NM.Modules.FlexEventsCreate.Models.FlexEventViewModel>
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Helpers

<input type="file" id="fileUp"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

**Controller**

```
[DnnHandleError]
public class ItemController : DnnController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowForm(FlexEventViewModel flexEvent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var file = Request.Files;

            if (file.Count != 0)
            {
                //do something  
            }

            //return RedirectToDefaultRoute();
        }

        return View(flexEvent);
    }
}
```

The rendered DNN HTML looks like this (I have simplified it)

```
<form method="post" action="/Test" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Begin Content areas -->
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-9 columns">
                <div id="dnn_LeftPane">
                    <div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DnnModule-747">
                        <a name="747"></a>

                        <div class="DnnF_Title_h1 SpacingBottom">
                            <h1><span id="dnn_ctr747_dnnTITLE_titleLabel" class="TitleH1"></span>

    </h1>
                            <div id="dnn_ctr747_ContentPane">
                                <!-- Start_Module_747 -->
                                <div id="dnn_ctr747_ModuleContent">
                                    <div id="dnn_ctr747_ShowForm_Prog" class="RadAjax RadAjax_Default" style="display:none;">
                                        <div class="raDiv">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="raColor raTransp">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="dnn_ctr747_dnn_ctr747_ShowForm_UPPanel">
                                        <div id="dnn_ctr747_ShowForm_UP">
                                            <!-- 2013.2.717.40 -->
                                            <div id="mvcContainer-747">

                                                <input type="file" id="fileUp">
                                                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Show your form tag. Does it have the necessary `enctype= multipart/form-data` attribute

Comment: In DNN the form tag is at the beginning of the page therefore when you build a module, you do not include it.


<form method="post" action="/Test" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Any updates to this question?  Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did do an upload in an MVC module using the [dropzone jquery component](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) - which may help you.  See my sample [Restaurant Menu project](https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/tree/master/RestaurantMenu.MVC) on github.

First, include the dropzone script and css:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement
@{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/DesktopModules/MVC/DotNetNuclear/RestaurantMenu/Resources/dropzone/css/dropzone.css");
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Dnn.DnnPage, "~/DesktopModules/MVC/DotNetNuclear/RestaurantMenu/Resources/dropzone/js/dropzone.min.js", 100);
}
```

Then place a container div for the upload component:

```
<div id="dZUpload" class="uploadform dropzone no-margin dz-clickable">
      <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
</div>
```

Initialize the component and tell it what type and how many files can be uploaded:

```
$("#dZUpload").dropzone({
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif",
    url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Menu")',
    maxFiles: 1, // Number of files at a time
    maxFilesize: 1, //in MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxfilesexceeded: function (file) {
        alert('You have uploaded more than 1 Image. Only the first file will be uploaded!');
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Change the acceptedFiles to the mimetypes you are restricting ("application/pdf", etc).  Change the maxFiles to limit how many files they can upload at a time.

Write an MVC controller action to respond to the Dropzone file upload url.  You can see it expects an action method "Upload" on the controller "Menu" (MenuController.Upload):

```
public JsonResult Upload()
{
    string imageUrl = string.Empty;
    string imgPath = Server.MapPath("~/Portals/0/Restaurant/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(imgPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(imgPath);
    }

    foreach (string s in Request.Files)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[s];
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(imgPath, fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            imageUrl = string.Format("/Portals/0/Restaurant/{0}", fileName);
        }
    }

    return Json(new { img = imageUrl, thumb = imageUrl });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, let me try and incorporate that into my module!